# IntelliJ http client save JSON value as variable not working for variable names with - character

Tags: json, intellij-idea, environment-variables, intellij-14

My GET Request:

```
### Bank token idclaim
GET {{IdClaimEndpoint}}/tokens/v1/id
Content-Type: application/json

> {% client.log(response.body.id-claim); %}
```

Response body:

```
{
  "documentation": "http://go/proofs",
  "id-claim": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGc"
}
```

Error from Response handler:

```
ReferenceError: "claim" is not defined. (<jsHandler script>#143)Script finished
```

If I try to extract value of documentation it works fine but not working for "id-claim".

I tried wrapping it within single/double quotes and also saving it to env variable and passing the env variable as {{id-claim}}, none of them worked.

Comment: Tried this :
> {% let claim = "id-claim"; client.log(response.body.claim); %}
Error from Response handler:
missing ; before statement (<jsHandler script>#134)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is JavaScript. You can use response.body['id-claim'] syntax. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#syntax

For example, the next request works fine:

```
POST https://httpbin.org/post
Content-Type: application/json

{
"my-json-value": "value"
}

{%
// 'json' is a property in HTTPBin response JSON
client.log(response.body.json["my-json-value"])
%}
```

Comment: Correct. That was simple.
In my case this worked fine:      
> {% client.log(response.body["id-claim"]); client.global.set("banktokenidclaim", response.body["id-claim"]); %}

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
> {%
client.log(JSON.stringify(response.body.valueOf()).replace("\"documentation\":\"http:\/\/go\/proofs\",\"id-claim\":\"", "").replace("\"","").replace("{","").replace("}",""));
client.global.set("banktokenidclaim", JSON.stringify(response.body.valueOf()).replace("\"documentation\":\"http:\/\/go\/proofs\",\"id-claim\":\"", "").replace("\"","").replace("{","").replace("}",""));
%}
```

But is a lot of work for a simple thing. Not sure if there exists a easier/better solution.

Comment: More like a workaround.